# Lexicographic sorting with a Trie

Tags: java, trie

[image]According to Wikipedia, regarding a trie:

> Lexicographic sorting of a set of keys can be accomplished with a simple trie-based algorithm as follows:
>
> - Insert all keys in a trie.
> - Output all keys in the trie by means of pre-order traversal, which results in output that is in lexicographically increasing order.

However, this is my testing with my standard trie implementation:

```java
Trie trie = new Trie();
trie.add("doll");
trie.add("ball");
trie.add("bat");
trie.add("dork");
trie.add("dorm");
trie.add("send");
trie.add("sense");
trie.add("sent");
```

Pre-order printout:

```
     public List<String> allWords(){

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(root == null){
        return words;
    }

    StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder();
    getAllWords(root.children,prefix,words);

    return words;
}

// depth first search
private void getAllWords(List<TrieNode> children, StringBuilder prefix,  List<String> words){

    for(int i= 0; i<children.size(); i++){
        TrieNode child = children.get(i);
        if(!child.isWord_){
            prefix.append(child.data_);
            allWordsHelper(child.children, prefix, words);
        }else{
            prefix.append(child.data_);
            words.add(prefix.toString());
        }
        prefix.deleteCharAt(prefix.length()-1);
    }
}
```

And the output order is: `doll dork dorm ball bat send sense sent`

What does the 'lexicographic sorting' mean? It seems the output order is more related to the insertion order, not lexicographic order. Am I getting something wrong?
Take this tree as one example, the pre-order printout would be "to tea ted ten a inn". Where is the lexicographic order?

Comment: Are you making a pre-order traversal when printing the output?

Comment: Yes， pre-order. Since 'doll' is first inserted, it must be output first even in pre-order. Under the root, the first level of characters are 'd  b s'. With pre-order, it prints all words with 'd' prefix first.

Comment: Just think about the standard Trie data structure and the 2-step algorithm described above, there isn't any piece of information to guarantee lexicographical ordering. How could that be possible？

Comment: If you do an inorder traversal and visit the children of each node in sorted order, you should get back all of the elements in sorted order. Could you show us the code you're using for an inorder traversal and for storing the nodes in the trie?

Comment: But wiki says it's pre-order to achieve lexicographical ordering.

Comment: Just take the tree above as one example, your inorder algorithm won't work either. It seems the nodes have to be inserted in some order. Otherwise, no way to do that.

Comment: Seems to the children are not sorted by the trie and your code does not sort the children.  Have you tried sorting the children by `data_`?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of saying about lexicographical sorting using tries is :

The preorder of the nodes in a trie is the same as the lexicographical order of the strings they represent assuming the children of a node are ordered by the edge labels.

Now, if you tried this in your code, pre-order traversal should give you strings in lexicographic order.

Here is the reference which has an example : http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/tpkarkka/opetus/12s/spa/lecture02.pdf

Answer (score 0):

According to me, it should be `Inorder` traversal. One can traverse the trie such that all branches having keys less than root's value are processed first, then root's value is printed, and lastly all values greater than root's value. This is **standard** `inorder` traversal but the only point I wanted to make was, you will have to write custom logic for processing all branches having keys less than root's key first, which in a regular binary tree would just have been root.left, but since there is not left/right in trie we'll have to fall back on the essence of left and right in a BST.( whose inorder also outputs lexicographically sorted values.`)

Answer (score 0):

Can Also be done by TreeMap -

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

class TrieNodeTreeMap{
    Map<Character, TrieNodeTreeMap> children;
    String key;

    public TrieNodeTreeMap(){
        key = null;
        children = new TreeMap<>();
    }
}
public class LexicographPrint {
    public static TrieNodeTreeMap root;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        root = new TrieNodeTreeMap();
        //String s = "lexicographic sorting of a set";
        String s = "lexicographic sorting of a set of keys can be accomplished with " +
                "a simple trie based algorithm we insert all keys in a trie output " +
                "all keys in the trie by means of preorder traversal which results " +
                "in output that is in lexicographically increasing order preorder " +
                "traversal is a kind of depth first traversal";
        String dict[] = s.split(" ");
        for (String word : dict){
            insertion(root,word);
        }

        lexicographlySort(root);
    }

    private static void insertion(TrieNodeTreeMap root, String str){
        TrieNodeTreeMap curr = root;

        for (char ch : str.toCharArray()){
            if (!curr.children.containsKey(ch)){
                curr.children.put(ch, new TrieNodeTreeMap());
            }

            curr  = curr.children.get(ch);
        }

        curr.key = str;
    }

    private static void lexicographlySort(TrieNodeTreeMap root){
        TrieNodeTreeMap curr = root;
        if (curr == null)
            return;

        for (Map.Entry<Character, TrieNodeTreeMap> entry : curr.children.entrySet()){
            TrieNodeTreeMap tmp = entry.getValue();
            if (tmp.key != null)
                System.out.println(tmp.key);
            lexicographlySort(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Naveen kumar singh Please elaborate your answer with proper explanation.